# Tooltip cut off because of overflow

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, overflow

I would like to have a tooltip outside a scrolling container (when the tooltip is centered). However the tooltip always cuts off because the scrolling container has an `overflow: auto` attribute.

[image]

This demo I made demonstrates what my issue is: https://jsfiddle.net/ny610aL1/1/

Because of the tooltip, the `position: relative` is on the item instead. I think this prevents that i move the container outside with css.

Is there any way that this is possible using CSS?

Comment: Are tooltips really needed? can't you hide and show the tooltips' text next to the items, with `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`? So they take the space they need. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ny610aL1/2/

Comment: yes, the tooltips will be used more as some extra information

Comment: Your tooltip is being cut off because of `left: -20px`, if you set it to `0`, it seems to solve the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/ke4hfq74/1/

Comment: That's the plan, the tooltip should actually be centered, but because the name is sometimes too long it goes  out of the box. By putting the left -20px i tried to show the cutting off text.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to put the tooltip container outside the overflow container.
These dialog layers usually end-up before the closing tag of body for this very reason => positioning.

Tooltip widgets often come with JavaScript libraries attached (jQuery-UI, Bootstrap, ...).

In a CSS only solution, you'll have to be happy with the fact that positioning is not calculated but anticipated.